# Problema Array método .shift()

Tags: javascript, array, console

Tengo un problema cuando utilizo el metodo de Array .shift() de javascript puro. Resulta
que el metodo .shift() Elimina el primer elemento del Array y nos devuelve luego ese elemento
si creamos una variable para ese elemento eliminado en especifico, a continuación el codigo
para explicar mi problema.

```
let numeros=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(numeros);
numeros.shift();
console.log(numeros);
let deleteElement=numeros.shift();
console.log(deleteElement);
```

Como se puede apreciar tengo un Array: de 5 elementos, en teoria me deberia eliminar el primer elemento que sería 1 lo cual lo hace como se aprecia de forma siguiente en la respuesta de consola, sin embargo al escribir la variable para mostrar en consola el elemento elimina como se aprecia la variable de nombre deleteElement, me aparece es el numero 2 cuando debería ser el numero 1. Y ese es mi problema el porque me aparece 2 y no 1 como debería de ser de acuerdo a lo que significa el metodo .shift()

A continuación el resultado que me aparece en consola:

(5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  "El resultado del primer console.log"

(4) [2, 3, 4, 5]     "El resultado del segundo console.log"

2                   "El resultado del tercer console.log con la variable deleteElement"

Comment: Lo que pasa es que `shift` modifica el arreglo original. Después de llamarlo por primera vez al arreglo solo le quedan 4 elementos iniciando con el número 2.

Comment: El resultado es correcto, estás haciendo un primer `array.shift()` que efectivamente elimina el primer elemento del `array`. Cuando asignas el resultado del segundo uso de `shift()` lo haces a partir del `array` que ya no contiene el elemento `1` sino que contiene números a partir del 2.

Comment: Wow, tienes absoluta razón amigo, ahora mi duda es; como podría hacer aparecer en console el 1 es decir sin que me contara desde el 2 ?

Comment: El primer `shift()` es el que saca el uno, lo puedes asignar a una variable

Comment: O simplemente puedes hacer: `console.log(array.shift());` en caso de que no quieras almacenarlo en ninguna variable. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

EL PROBLEMA QUE TIENES ES QUE ESTAS USANDO DOS VECES EL METODO shift, A PARTIR DE ESO TU CONFUCION

```
let numeros=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(numeros);
let deleteElement=numeros.shift();
console.log(numeros);
console.log(deleteElement);
deleteElement=numeros.shift();
console.log(numeros);
console.log(deleteElement);
```